# Solve "does not contain a definition for 'OfType'" error message?

Tags: c#

This is my code and appear an unknown error:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {

            object a = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["price"].Value;
            object b = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["tedad"].Value;
            double aNumber = 0;
            double bNumber = 0;
            if (a != null)
                aNumber = Double.Parse(a.ToString());
            if (b != null)
                bNumber = Double.Parse(b.ToString());
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["total"].Value = aNumber * bNumber;
            dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
        }
        decimal sum = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
           .Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["total"].Value));
        txtDate.Text  = sum.ToString();
```

an error like this meaning for `OfType()`:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' WindowsFormsApplication1test

Comment: OfType does not exist as a method to call

Comment: Writing this code is pointless, all rows of a DataGridView are of type DataGridViewRow.

Comment: @HansPassant DataGridViewRowCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>, so this helps by letting the `row` parameter's type be inferred. `OfType` still doesn't make sense though, it should be [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you have :

```
using System.Linq;
```

### [Enumerable.OfType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

- **Namespace:**  System.Linq
- **Assembly:**  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)

[image]

Comment: @Elena - do you mean you typed it in at the top of the code file and it doesnt work?

Comment: i mean "using System.Linq;" in my form's above," Linq" doesn't appear at all....why?????????????????????????

Comment: @Elena, make sure you are using .Net framework 3.5 or higher, also right click on project references and make sure you have `System.Core` added

Comment: @Habib i dont have system.core in project refrence! where can i find it?

Comment: @Elena, I have added a screen shot to a sample project.

Comment: @Elena, Got to project, right click, add References -> there go to .Net tab and add reference to `System.Core`

Comment: @BlackFrog thanks alot, i tried it but i have not System.core

Comment: @BlackFrog how can i give you my screen shot of that?

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you are referencing the `System.Linq` namespace, targetting .NET 3.5 or higher, include `System.Core` as a reference.

Comment: i have .net 3.5 and .net4 in my system

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, just sum together the ["total"] values and put them in the txtDate.Text field.